# Is it possible to use a list of values from a views display as exposed filter of another view?

Tags: views

I have a view with a page display where I have some fields showing. One of the fields is field `foo`. I want the user to be able to filter the view by the `foo` value, choosing one or multiple values. I want the items of `foo` to be available in a list. Can I accomplish this using the data of another display where I have all the unique values of `foo`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this,

Install the entity reference module. 
Create an entity reference view (like creating a block or content pane). The results in this view will be your exposed filter.
Create an entity reference field in your content type.
In that field's settings, select the above view.
Use this field as an exposed filter.

Without more detail, I can't really describe how to set it up accurately but this is generally the accepted method.